# How do I find corresponding clusters in independent samples?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

Lets suppose you believe that observations in your data come from K natural but not directly observable categories and you wish to identify these categories with minimal prior assumptions, so you find an appropriate metric and do unsupervised clustering on your data. Let's suppose you want clusters that are stable over multiple sites and time-periods. So you collect Q independent samples from various locations and time-periods, and classify each sample $Q_i$ into clusters $Q_{i1} ... Q_{ik}$.

Now you need to map $Q_{11}$ to a corresponding $Q_{ik}$, $Q_{12}$ to a corresponding $Q_{ik}$, etc. for $i\ne1$ and the ordering of the clusters $Q_{ik}$ for each sample $Q_i$ is not informative.

My questions:

1. What are the commonly used names (or search terms) for this type of
   problem or for the sub-disciplines of statistics that deal with it?
2. What are the commonly used names (or search terms) for a variant of
   this type of problem where K can be different for each sample (i.e.
   data driven) and you are willing accept a certain number of clusters
   in each sample that don't have corresponding clusters in other
   samples?
3. Are there any recommended textbooks or other starting
   points for getting acquainted with this type of problem (not
   clustering itself, but specifically collating clusters from multiple
   independent samples)?

Thanks. Sorry about the broad question-- I'm not looking for a complete answer, only for some pointers on what to read to understand this field (for an individual who already has some training in classical statistics and programming).